# Samba - only allow users access their folder (and custom dirs)

Tags: samba

Currently, users in our samba directory can access any folders, including each others so I've found that by including this line in the config file `valid users = %S` uncommented, users can only access their home directories.

Now the only problem is that other folders are not accessible for everyone and I can't seem to have it working.

How do I make the home/**USER** accessible to **USER** while keeping other dirs open for everyone?

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED:

Apparently even though the samba users aren't part of the host OS, they are somehow the owners of the the file. A quick `ls` on the the `/home/` directory on the linux host shows that there's 775 permission for everyone.

I did a quick:

```
chmod *my-samba-base*/home/ 770 *
```